# OR-Tools VRP: Constrain locations to be served by same vehicle

Tags: modeling, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I would like to constrain locations to be served by the same vehicle.
I used capacity-constraints for achieving this. Say we have `l = [[1,2], [3,4]]` which means that location 1, 2 must be served by the same vehicle and 3, 4 as well. So 1, 2 ends up on `route_1` and 3, 4 on `route_2`

My code for achieving this is:

```py
for idx, route_constraint in enumerate(l):
    vehicle_capacities = [0] * NUM_VEHICLES
    vehicle_capacities[idx] = len(route_constraint)
    route_dimension_name = 'Same_Route_' + str(idx)

    def callback(from_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return 1 if from_node in route_constraint else 0

    same_routes_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(callback)

    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        same_routes_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        vehicle_capacities,  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        route_dimension_name)
```

The idea is that 1,2 have a capacity demand of each 1 unit (all others have zero). As only vehicle 1 has a capacity of 2 it is the only one able to serve 1,2.

This seems to work fine if len(l) == 1. If greater the solver is not able to find a solution if though I put into l pairs of locations which were on the same route without the above code (hence without the above capacity constraints.

1. Is there a more elegant way to model my requirement?
2. Why does the solver fail to find a solution?

I have also considered the possibility of dropping visits (at a high cost) to give the solver the possibility to start from a solution which drops visits such that it will find his way fro this point to a solution without any drops. I had no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each stop has a vehicle var whose values determine what vehicle is allowed to visit the stop. If you want to have stops 1 and 2 serviced by vehicle 0 use a member constraint on the vehicle var of each stop and set it to `[0]`. Since you might have other constraints that make stops optional add the value -1 to the list. It is a special value that indicates that the stop is not serviced by a vehicle.

In Python:

```py
n2x = index_manager.NodeToIndex
cpsolver = routing_model.solver()

for stop in [1,2]:
    vehicle_var = routing_model.VehicleVar(n2x(stop))
    values = [-1, 0]
    cpsolver.Add(cpsolver.MemberCt(vehicle_var, values))
```